# Sum data horizontally from a work schedule, with criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, typescript, excel-formula

I have a work schedule with data listed horizontally. I need to sum the hours in the schedule based on a few different criteria. The rows listed are the person's name, with the hours available, the shift they are working, and the machine they are working on. I've attached a picture of the layout.

Basically, I want to sum to total hours listed by machine, shift, and week number. So in the attachment, if the shift is 1, the machine 300, and the week number 40 (top row), it should return the value of 8.

I've tried regular sumifs, attempted sumproduct (never really used before), using all the columns vs just one column, and nothing. I've setup some named ranges in case that helped, but I'm still getting errors. I don't work with arrays too often, but thought maybe that would help as well.

[image: schedule picture]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm slowly learning TypeScript, so if that can somehow help I'm open to that as well.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a pretty complex equation due to your layout. If you have Excel 365, It would be much simpler.

You need to create an array of your entire table, then create mask arrays, then sum as required.

For instance, Here is an array of all values:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1:Z26),A1:Z26,0)
```

To create a mask to remove all but week 40, use:

```
=IF(A1:Z26=40,ISNUMBER(A1:Z26),0)
```

It gets harder to filter by shift and machine because you are filtering by row, but the info you need is on another row. Here is how to do it for shift 1:

```
=IF(OFFSET(A1:Z26,1,0)=1,ISNUMBER(A1:Z26),0)
```

The offset changes for machine. Here is how to do it for machine 300:

```
=IF(OFFSET(A1:Z26,2,0)=300,ISNUMBER(A1:Z26),0)
```

Now you need to multiply these all together. It will create an array of all the values on you spreadsheet, but the values you filtered out will be zero. Then sum the array:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:Z26),A1:Z26,0) * IF(A1:Z26=40,ISNUMBER(A1:Z26),0) * IF(OFFSET(A1:Z26,1,0)=1,ISNUMBER(A1:Z26),0) * IF(OFFSET(A1:Z26,2,0)=300,ISNUMBER(A1:Z26),0))
```